# Buck converter remote terminal

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, 12v

I'm testing a LED setup, I have a bench PSU going to Traco 5V buck converter that feeds 10 LEDs (SK6812). When I power the bench PSU on, before it hits 12V, the first LED in the strip flashes for a milisecond and then the strip loads its default "color".

Pardon my lack of knowledge, but this might be inrush or something? My goal is to hook this up to 12V battery so I would like to solve this problem and have a smooth on-power without this first led flashing on power.

The specs of my buck converter are attached - you can see it has Remote option, but I can't google it out what the remote terminal on the converter does and how to use it, is this a feature I should use in my case? Please help :)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "before it hits 12v"?  a bench psu should go from 0 to 12 instantly. pixels do normal have undefined behavior on power up, but you can try adding a cap to the 5v output to soak up the pre-boot stray voltage.

Comment: I figured it's an issue with the data line, has to be mitigated another way, via relay, it's a common issue on these controllers. But I'm still lost with buck converter remote terminal, whats the use of it, when or why would I need it.